# Sampling Encrypted image takes much time Android

Tags: android, encryption, android-imageview

I'm displaying images in imageView in a swiping fashion, It takes about 122 ~ 160 ms but when I encrypt the image and decrypt then displaying it , it takes about 600 - 900 ms

What confuses me is that the time is not the decryption time, it is the image sampling time

```
Ciphered 

imgInput  = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    CipherInputStream cs = getCipherStream(imgInput);
                    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    Log.i(TAG,"Ciphered: "+ (endTime - startTime));

                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //decode ciphered
                    bmp = ImagingUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResourceMemOpt(cs, 800,
                            800);
                    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    Log.i(TAG,"Decoding ciphered: "+ (endTime - startTime));

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

unChiphered

```
imgInput = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //decode non-ciphereed
                    bmp = ImagingUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResourceMemOpt(imgInput, 800,
                            800);
                    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    Log.i(TAG,"decoding unciphered: "+ (endTime - startTime));

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Decoding Code (recommended in another post at stackoverflow)

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[0];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                if (len != 0) {
                    if (count + len > byteArr.length) {
                        byte[] newbuf = new byte[(count + len) * 2];
                        System.arraycopy(byteArr, 0, newbuf, 0, count);
                        byteArr = newbuf;
                    }

                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, byteArr, count, len);
                    count += len;
                }
            }

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, count, options);

            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                    reqHeight);
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            int[] pids = { android.os.Process.myPid() };

            //  MemoryInfo myMemInfo = mAM.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids)[0];
            // Log.e(TAG, "dalvikPss (decoding) = " + myMemInfo.dalvikPss);

            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, count, options);
```

The method I use for decryption

```
public CipherInputStream getCipherStream(InputStream imageis) throws Throwable
    {

        // Open the input stream
        InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("inserva.key");

        Cipher c = new EncryptonUtils(is).getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE); //cipher.init(mode,secretKey,paramSpec);


        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(imageis, c);

        return cis ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be read time.  The cipher stream is in memory, the file stream is not.  YOu're probably making too many disc access commands by reading small chunks from disk.  Try wrapping the FileInputStream in a BufferedReader and seeing if it improves things.

I do see you're reading in 1K at a time, but that just isn't efficient-  the size of the smallest readable unit on disk is oing to be at least 4K, probably 8K or more, so you're reading the same data multiple times.

Comment: I took your advice in changing the 1024 to 4096

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  try {
   while ((len = br.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    if (len != 0) {
     if (count + len > byteArr.length) {
char[] newbuf = new char[(count + len) * 2];
      System.arraycopy(byteArr, 0, newbuf, 0, count);
      byteArr = newbuf;
     }

     System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, byteArr, count, len);
     count += len;
    }
   }
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   
   BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(new String(byteArr).getBytes(), 0, count, options);

Comment: the decryption time is the same and may be more and the image is not returned correctly (not displayed)